# How do I get the event that took me to state in Spring Web Flow?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

Suppose that I have a view-state targeted by many states. So many of them will have transitions with destination this state. For some of them, I want to display certain data on the page. So suppose if from state A->B then don't display, if C->B display. 
I thought that if I knew the event that triggered the transition, I could easily do this... but I can't find a way (I am new to SWF). 
Do you know how to do that? Or alternative ways to get the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar to this using a `FlowExecutionListener`.  `FlowExecutionListenerAdapter` is provided as a base class for adding behavior on transition,  state change, etc.  An example of how to register such a listener can be found [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.0-m1/reference/practical.html)  in the docs.  Each method is passed a Definition that contains meta data about the event.  From that meta data you can determine if the event is one you're interested in and execute your custom logic.

Hope that helps.